# [NativeScript]: Metadata for Darwin.strlen found but symbol not available at runtime nativescript

Tags: ios, nativescript, ios14, nativescript-angular

I am working on the native script and created and published the iOS app to the app store.
The app is working smoothly till iOS 14.6 but from iOS 14.7 onwards I am getting

```
Metadata for "Darwin.strlen" found but symbol not available at runtime. 
toCharPtr(file:///app/vendor.js:182294:30) 
at Database(file:///app/vendor.js:182382:32) 
at file:///app/bundle.js:830:27 
at SqLiteService(file:///app/bundle.js:826:20) 
at _createClass(file:///app/vendor.js:20966:28) 
at _createProviderInstance(file:///app/vendorjs:20938:38) 
at resolveNgModuleDep(file:///app/vendor.js:20902:44) 
at _createClass(file:///app/vendor.js:20974:50) 
at _createProviderInstance(file:///app/vendorjs:20938:38) 
at resolveNgModuleDep(file:///app/vendor.js:20902:44) 
at createClass(file:///app/vendor.js:21843:42) 
at createDirectivelnstance(file:///app/vendor.js:21714:31) 
at createViewNodes(file:///app/vendor.js:30074:59) 
at createRootView(file:///app/vendor.js:29988:20) 
at file:///app/vendor.js:21193:43 
at file:///app/vendor.js:27761:46 
at forEach([native code]) 
t file:///app/vendor.js:27483:51 
at file:///app/vendor.js:27451:45 
at onInvoke(file:///app/vendor.js:26943:39) 
at file:///app/vendor.js:147266:49 
at file:///app/vendor.js:148011:37 
at onInvokeTask(file:///app/vendor.js:26934:43) 
at file:///app/vendor.js:147316:57 
at drainMicroTaskQueue(file:///app/vendor.js:147723:42) 
at file:///app/vendor.js:134241:44 
at file://)app/vendor.js:80750:31 
at [native code] at file:///app/vendor.js:60836:36 
at file:///app/vendor.js:60828:30 
at [native code] 
at file:///app)vendor.js:60701:32 
at UlApplicationMain([native code]) 
at run(file:///app/vendor.js:60977:26) 
at file:///app/vendor.js:134272:26 
at file:///app/vendor.js:134173:38 
at file:///app/vendor.js:134153:26 
at file:///app/bundle.js:12323:66 
at webpack_require_(file:///app/runtime.js:75:34) 
at checkDeferredModules(file:///app/runtime.js:44:42) 
at webpackJsonpCallback(file:///app/runtime.js:31:39) 
at anonymous(file:///app)bundle.js:2:61) 
at evaluate([native code]) 
at moduleEvaluation([native code]) 
at [native code] 
at asyncFunctionResume([native code]) 
at [native code] 
at promiseReactionJob([native code])
```

this error and app is crashing on runtime, I am not sure whats wrong with the updated OS, can some please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears in iOS 14.7 Apple removed/hid some functionality.  This issue:
https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-sqlite/issues/171 is tracking the actual issue and as I stated in that issue, I have a fix awaiting final testing before it is released.

NS-Sqlite 2.8.2 or later should fix the issue.

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of that plugin)